# cross platform localisation of text: Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, string, localization

while developing an app for two platforms: iOS and Android, I've decided to have a central place of taking care of the localisation of string values. The aim is to have the strings synchronised between the iOS and Android apps, and not to care of modifying them in both projects each time separately... do you have any ideas how to tackle this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tour => Don't ask about... *Product or service recommendations or comparisons, Requests for lists of things...*

Comment: removed the question about a library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most "non-pain" way to setup will be - name all strings the same, and then use simple tools like:
https://localise.biz/free/converter/ios-to-android